# Почему в парсинге сайта мне выводит -1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Делал парсер для сайта на `python`. юзал библиотеки `BeautifulSoup` и `requests`. Захотел вывести названия фильмов, но выдает это. не получается вытащить текст, ибо '-1' это тип данных `int`, и он конфликтует с `str`.

```
-1
<strong>Проклятый путь</strong>
-1
<strong>Унесенные призраками</strong>
-1
<strong>Адаптация</strong>
-1
```

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.film.ru/movies'
site = 'https://www.film.ru'
res = requests.get(URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

a = soup.find('div', class_='rating infinite_scroll')

for i in a:
    strong = i.find('strong')
    print(strong)
```

в чем ошибка?

Comment: Кроме названия фильма в этом div есть еще `<strong>10/10</strong>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `css-селектор` `div.rating.infinite_scroll > a`, чтобы описать получения тегов `<a>`, которые напрямую вложены (для этого указывается `>`) в `<div>` с `class="rating infinite_scroll"`, а там будет просто получить ссылку на фильм, на постер и т.п.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/71802f0d0cf22c1a81ca34d0dfe03377ba2ca458/html_parsing/www_film_ru__movies.py#L17)

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.film.ru/movies'
rs = requests.get(URL)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for a in root.select('div.rating.infinite_scroll > a'):
    title = a.strong.get_text(strip=True)
    url = urljoin(rs.url, a['href'])
    print(title, url)

# Проклятый путь https://www.film.ru/articles/semeynaya-drama-s-tommi-ganom-v-ruke
# Унесенные призраками https://www.film.ru/articles/klassika-anime-unesennye-prizrakami
# Адаптация https://www.film.ru/articles/lukavoe-naglyadnoe-posobie-po-ekranizacii
# ...
# Первый мститель: Другая война https://www.film.ru/articles/so-schitom-ili-na-schite
```

Comment: может быть глупый вопрос. но я новичок)
почему вы ставите '>' в 'div.rating.infinite_scroll > a' ?

Comment: @РоманАноним, забыл добавить в описание, это для получения прямых детей после `>`, т.е. именно тех `a`, что у того `div`'а. Если не указывать `>`, то селектор может вернуть детей на нижних уровнях, т.е. рекурсивно их найти

Comment: уууууууф, все сложно и непонятно, но интересно. спасибо за ответ и помощь! буду разбираться дальше

Answer (score 1):

наверное не лучшее решение но работает для данного случая(а почему выводятся цифры вам написали в комментариях)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = 'https://www.film.ru/movies'
res = requests.get(URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

a = soup.find('div', class_ = 'rating infinite_scroll')

for i in a:
    strong = i.find('strong')
    if type(i.find('strong'))!=int:
        print(strong.get_text())
```